# A desgined Form in theme.res file corupted

Tags: codenameone

I have not update this themes.res (using the CN designer for a while) suddently after 1 day I do some update in my code and sent an Android build to rebuild, I found one of the form is not working.. when the form going to show, the apps through

'java.lang.String com.codename1.q.r.be()' on a null object reference.

After investigate, I found the UI Designer is able to open the theme.res file, but not able to show that particular form "Report".

[image]

I rerun the designer in command line to view any error through by the UI Designer, and it is:

```
~]$ java -jar ~/.codenameone/designer_1.jar 
2016-12-21 17:51:09.562:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.0.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2016-12-21 17:51:09.623:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000 STARTING
Dec 21, 2016 5:51:09 PM org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage getId
WARNING: unspecified resource Application.id using ResourceEditorApp
java.lang.RuntimeException: Component not found use UIBuilder.registerCustomComponent(, class);
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponentType(UIBuilder.java:1530)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponent(UIBuilder.java:977)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponent(UIBuilder.java:1377)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponent(UIBuilder.java:1377)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createContainer(UIBuilder.java:413)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createContainer(UIBuilder.java:398)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView$11.getIconImage(ResourceEditorView.java:429)
    at com.codename1.designer.HorizontalList.createButton(HorizontalList.java:285)
    at com.codename1.designer.HorizontalList.refresh(HorizontalList.java:164)
    at com.codename1.designer.HorizontalList$2.treeNodesInserted(HorizontalList.java:139)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.fireTreeNodeAdded(EditableResources.java:3328)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView$LoadResourceFileAction.afterComplete(ResourceEditorView.java:4208)
    at com.codename1.ui.resource.util.BlockingAction$4.run(BlockingAction.java:91)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Component not found use UIBuilder.registerCustomComponent(, class);
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponentType(UIBuilder.java:1530)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponent(UIBuilder.java:977)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponent(UIBuilder.java:1377)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createComponent(UIBuilder.java:1377)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createContainer(UIBuilder.java:413)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.createContainer(UIBuilder.java:398)
    at com.codename1.designer.UserInterfaceEditor.<init>(UserInterfaceEditor.java:586)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.getResourceEditor(EditableResources.java:3207)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView.setSelectedResource(ResourceEditorView.java:657)
    at com.codename1.designer.HorizontalList$1.actionPerformed(HorizontalList.java:117)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.designer.UserInterfaceEditor.<init>(UserInterfaceEditor.java:597)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.getResourceEditor(EditableResources.java:3207)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView.setSelectedResource(ResourceEditorView.java:657)
    at com.codename1.designer.HorizontalList$1.actionPerformed(HorizontalList.java:117)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Somebody please advice whats happen?

Answer (score 1):

To workaround the issue you can probably delete and recreate that form. Assuming you find a way to consistently reproduce this I'd like to know what that is.

Before doing that copy the project to the side, open that project. Assuming you are using NetBeans go to project properties and select the option to convert the old GUI builder project to a new GUI builder project in the project properties under the Codename One section.

Once that is done go to the files section of the view and look at the project. Open `res/guibuilder` and find the `.gui` file matching this form. Look in it you should see a component with a "problematic" type value... If not please edit your question and place the XML of the `.gui` file there.

Comment: I tried before, and just retry again your suggestion, by closed the project in netbeans, and open again after uncheck the XML Team Mode., not working.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a different direction to solve this

Comment: I tried, the converter show the same error in the status box, and the Report form just not shown inside the *.gui package.

I think this problematic form is using some component(s) that has been removed from the newly updated gui builder. I have to redo the Form again.

Comment: That's my thought too but we don't generally remove components that are available... The component type should be given when you get that error message and it's currently blank.